# Bootstrap3, how to have dropdown menu on the toggle button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please run [this coding](http://bootply.com/81768) using mobile view.

I copied the code from bootstrap documentation, I wish to have the toggle button (triple bar button) when I pressed the button I want to get a dropdown menu.  But I really don't understand the concept of how to have a dropdown on toggle button.

Please show me sample coding, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think using the drop downs from a right-aligned button is going to be tricky if not painful. Also the menu items are probably too small to be comfortable to tap on a touch device.

How about the navbar-collapse instead?

```html
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".Kongthaps-navbar">
...
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse Kongthaps-navbar">
```

Notice how the data-target class is used to identify the toggled menu.

Full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/yNHpf/3/

As for your version with a regular drop down, the trigger has to be inside the `<div class="dropdown">` tag, and the data-toggle needs to be `data-toggle="dropdown"` instead of `data-toggle="collapse"`. Also, I think there can't be a data-target (otherwise it doesn't work)

Here's your example, semi-working:

http://jsfiddle.net/6jF9x/3/

I leave the positioning of the drop down up to you ;-)

I use the first technique in my themes, check out [my theme Tales](http://demo.hackerthemes.com/tales/html-version/v2/) which I already migrated to BS3 for a real life example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Kongthap: Thanks. Please mark as correct answer if you're satisfied :)